# NumPad Not Working In Debian

Tags: debian

All the solutions I've found on Google are for different distro or older version of Debian and Shift+Numlock didn't resolve the issue, Also I can't find the Preferences->Keyboard->Mouse Keys. I'm using Gnome.

There's no way to change Region Language and keyboard format, I only have US / Imperial and I'm using AZERTY format. I'm so confused.

My numlock works somehow because when I press 4, the mouse cursor goes to the left direction (8 to the upper, 6 to the right, 2 to the down etc....) I can also use the keys to page up or down etc... So physically the numlock works (at least the directions and page up/down, position 1 and end, print etc.) I do not know why the number functionalilites are not activated. Do I have to configure something?

I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: I know Gnome via the Tweak Tool, has keymapping and other keyboard switches that are configurable. Believe they're off by default. Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a mac aluminum keyboard which doesn't even have a numlock key. Anyways, you can solve this problem by installing the [numlockx](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=numlockx) Debian package, then running it during your X session, then set it up to start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

On my Debian 10, I solved this by

> sudo apt-get install numlockx

Now one has to activate numlocks, I simply add `numlockx on` in my `.bash_profile` (may be not the best way but it does it's job.